# SaltStack mongo_return not working with mongo AUTH

Tags: mongodb, salt-stack

I am using saltstack for doing some automation stuff and i am having problems with mongo authetication. I am running:

```
salt 'sw1' test.ping --return mongo_return
```

and i have the following config in /etc/salt/master:

```
mongo.db: 'saltdata'
mongo.host: 'mongohost'
mongo.user: 'saltuser'
mongo.password: 'saltuserpassword'
```

I have restarted the master but I get the log:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command insert requires authentication
```

I have tried with users created in 'admin' db but also in 'saltdata' db.
If I don't use AUTH in mongo, it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem solved. The config should not go into /etc/salt/master but in the config of proxy-minions (most likely /etc/salt/proxy), because the minions themselves are storing the data into mongo.
One more thing: The user used for mongo AUTH, should be inside the database "saltdata" in the above example. The  'mongo.authdb' setting does not exist/work for SALT.RETURNERS.MONGO_RETURN.